# Remove last name in billing address?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, eav, address

I am using Magento1.9 I followed below mention step after that i got error message

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code = 'lastname'
```

**/app/code/local/Mage/customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php:**

```
 /* if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getLastname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
         $this->addError(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the last name.'));
     }
*/
```

**/app/code/local/Mage/customer/Model/Customer.php**

```
/*        if (!Zend_Validate::is( trim($this->getLastname()) , 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The last name cannot be empty.');
    }
*/
```

**/app/code/local/Mage/customer/etc/config.xml**

```
<lastname>
                    <billing>1</billing>
                    <shipping>1</shipping>
                    **<required>0</required>** // change from 1 to 0
                    <mapped>1</mapped>
     </lastname>
```

[image]

Comment: Check any files rewrite the customer.php

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you have this figured out by now but it might help someone else.

I am using Magento CE 1.9.2.  In addition to what you have already done, try this:

1. Comment/delete required class in `app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`. You might also have to do the shipping.phtml as well depending on your needs.
2. Change the validation rules in `customer_eav_attribute` table for the attribute id you are changing (get it from the `eav_attribute` table)

Comment: It's best practice to learn how to write the Magento SQL script for this, but if you know the ID alan-ch is likely spot on with the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I have used 1.9.2.4 and followed the below steps and it worked fine.

1. Remove the classes for JS validation from your templates.
   customer/widget/name.phtml
   Remove `class="required"` from the label relating to the ‘lastname’ field 
   Remove

   ```
   <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('lastname') ?> from the input relating to ‘lastname’
   ```
2. Copy your core files from:

   - /app/code/core/Mage/customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php
   - /app/code/core/Mage/customer/Model/Customer.php

   into:

   - /app/code/local/Mage/customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php
   - /app/code/local/Mage/customer/Model/Customer.php

   And comment out everything related to Zend validation of Lastname.

   /app/code/local/Mage/customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php:

   ```
     /*
     if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getLastname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
           $this->addError(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the last name.'));
       }
     */
   ```

   /app/code/local/Mage/customer/Model/Customer.php

   ```
      /*
       if (!Zend_Validate::is( trim($this->getLastname()) , 'NotEmpty')) {
           $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The last name cannot be empty.');
       }
      */
   ```
3. Update the config.xml file for customer
   /app/code/core/Mage/customer/etc/config.xml

   ```
   <lastname>
   <billing>1</billing>
   <shipping>1</shipping>
   <required>0</required>
   <mapped>1</mapped>
   </lastname>
   ```
4. Update the eav_attribute database table to remove the required flag

   ```
   UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code = 'lastname'
   ```
5. Update the validation rules in the customer_eav_attribute table

   ```
   UPDATE customer_eav_attribute SET
   validate_rules = 'a:1:{s:15:"max_text_length";i:255;}'
   WHERE customer_eav_attribute.attribute_id = 7;

   UPDATE customer_eav_attribute SET
   validate_rules = 'a:1:{s:15:"max_text_length";i:255;}'
   WHERE customer_eav_attribute.attribute_id = 22;
   ```