# magento how to remove last name from checkout page?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, register

i want to remove middle name & last name on checkout page only. from billing & shipping section. after analyse page code i found that. first/middle/last name coming from a file name.phtml path given below.

```
frontend/base/default/template/customer/widget/name.phtml
```

now i am able to remove middle/last name from here (**of-course i am not editing core file & made exact path in my theme and paste that file which works OK**)

but when i remove it from here. its also removed from registration page. So please tell me exactly what i have to do ?

my magento version is 1.9.X.X

- **My main issue is - when i am commenting last name in file its also removed from registration page**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

**Note : Don't Edit Core File Make a copy of Local File then edit**

It will remove mandatory fields of First Name & Last Name.

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code = 'lastname'
```

**/app/code/local/Mage/customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php:**

```
 /* if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getLastname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
         $this->addError(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the last name.'));
     }
*/
```

**/app/code/local/Mage/customer/Model/Customer.php**

```
/*        if (!Zend_Validate::is( trim($this->getLastname()) , 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The last name cannot be empty.');
    }
*/
```

**/app/code/local/Mage/customer/etc/config.xml**

```
<lastname>
                    <billing>1</billing>
                    <shipping>1</shipping>
                    **<required>0</required>** // change from 1 to 0
                    <mapped>1</mapped>
     </lastname>
```

Comment: it will remove last name form checkout page & not affect registration page right ?

Comment: it will affect all page because same file use all place

Comment: but my main issu is this. because when i am commenting last name in file its also removed from registration page

Comment: don't remove in name.phtml just remove require class

Comment: i tried it. but its not working. first i made local file and edit in it. but it was not working again i edited core file but still not working. cleared all cache, reindex & recompile but still not working. last name is still required.

Comment: Did you remove class required-entry in name.phtml

Comment: yes i removed related class from label & also remove input class print through php

Comment: getting error message last name is required.

Comment: even i also remove validation rule from custom_eav_attribute. i have same issue and getting same error as given below link. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82310/remove-last-name-in-billing-address

Comment: wow. that question was asked by you. let me know please how you solved it? because i had follow all your given steps + also removed all required class from name.phtml + remove validation rule from custom_eav_attribute for attribute id of last name

Comment: It shows any error

Comment: yes, "Last Name" Value is require. i was also getting something which mean like lenght must be more than 1. but after remove validation from custom_eacv_attribute. just getting this error https://www.dropbox.com/s/4pfcbtvjj9eilpi/Screenshot%202016-09-21%2013.58.35.png?dl=0

Comment: Hi, Kothari i solved it. Thank you very much for you precious time & help! Actually there was 2 rows in eav_attribute & customer_eav_attribute 7 i just remove it is_required & validation rule for 1 last name. i did not suppose there can b 2 rows. i thought its just single attribute used at multiple palces.