# magento2 remove lastname from checkoutpage

Tags: magento2, checkout-page

How to remove last name from checkout page in Magento2 ?

Comment: You will find your solution [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136916/magento-how-to-remove-last-name-from-checkout-page), it's what you require.

Comment: Let me know if it works, so i can post an answer :)

Comment: no its not working for me,

Comment: in my site there is  onstepcheckout module in magento2

Comment: you given the answer link of magento 1.9

Comment: Find my answer, is it worked ?

Comment: if any answer solves your concern then there is green right tick mark , hit that tick-mark for right answer that will help future readers.

Answer (score 3):

```
magento\vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\widget\name.phtml
```

- Paste above file in-to your theme.

And You will find a class named `field-name-lastname` remove this complete div for last name. (form **theme** folder, which you just copied form vendor)

Now run below query in your database to set `lastname` as optional for customer, because we just deleted the code for lastname.

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code = 'lastname' and `entity_type_id` = 1
```

and

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

It's working fine for Magento 2.2.2.
Let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 3):

Run below query into phpMyAdmin

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code = 'lastname' and `entity_type_id` = 1
```

Please overwrite theme below theme file.

```
magento\vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\widget\name.phtml
```

Please remove field-name-lastname from above overwrite theme file.

Clear the cache: php bin/magento cache:clean